# wxWidgets project compilation fails on Windows 10 with TDM-GCC

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets

I'm trying to compile wxWidgets 3.0.2 project on Windows 10 with TDM-GCC 4.7.1 32bit, I get this error below                      :

**Compilation**

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -std=c++11 -g -Wall -std=c++11 -g -Ilibrary\xerces-c-3.1.1\src -Ilibrary\mupdf-1.6\include -Ilibrary\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include -Ilibrary\wxWidgets-3.0.2\lib\wx\include\msw-unicode-3.0\ -Iinclude -IC:\TDM471-32\include -IC:\TDM471-32\include -c F:\Proj\Document.cpp -o obj\Debug\Document.o
```

**Errors**

```
In file included from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/string.h:45:0,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/object.h:19,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from F:\Proj\Document.h:4,
                 from F:\Proj\Document.cpp:1:
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrtbase.h: In function 'wchar_t* wxStrdup(const wchar_t*)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:680:68: error: 'wcsdup' was not declared in this scope
In file included from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/string.h:45:0,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/object.h:19,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from F:\Proj\Main.cpp:1:
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrtbase.h: In function 'wchar_t* wxStrdup(const wchar_t*)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:680:68: error: 'wcsdup' was not declared in this scope
In file included from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/crt.h:19:0,
In file included from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/crt.h:19:0,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/string.h:4305,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/object.h:19,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from F:\Proj\Document.h:4,
                 from F:\Proj\Document.cpp:1:
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen(const char*, size_t)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h:173:92: error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen(const wchar_t*, size_t)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h:187:95: error: 'wcsnlen' was not declared in this scope
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/string.h:4305,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/object.h:19,
                 from library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from F:\Proj\Main.cpp:1:
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen(const char*, size_t)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h:173:92: error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen(const wchar_t*, size_t)':
library\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/wxcrt.h:187:95: error: 'wcsnlen' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: did you do a configure first or you use Makefile directly?

Comment: What do you mean? wxWidgets is compiled, Im using it as library to complie cpp project that is linked with it.

Comment: so those errors come from the project and not the library itself? What version of gcc do you use? Where did you get it from? Did you build wx with the same compiler? How do you build you project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what explains your problem, but, in any case, using `-DwxUSE_UNICODE` on the command line is wrong, all `wxUSE_XXX` symbols are supposed to be defined as 0 or 1, not as nothing. But even `-DwxUSE_UNICODE=1` would be wrong as this can result in mismatches between CRT/SDK and wxWidgets headers. Instead you should predefine `_UNICODE` and/or `UNICODE` (the former is used by the CRT, the latter by the SDK, but the SDK will pick up the version with the underscore too) and wxWidgets will respect it as well.